# How to add checkout first step as a login step in magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, login

I need the first step is login form like as magento1 and remove login or email adding the field on shipping step.

add first step as [image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this?

Comment: Yes but Paid extension.

Comment: What extension if you wouldn't mind sharing.